# In GeoServer, how can I enforce user to lock out after certain attempts?

Tags: geoserver

In GeoServer, how can I enforce user to lock out after certain attempts?
I couldn't find way to enforce number of attempts when I create new user and set the password policy.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there is no way to do so.

New features and improvements welcomed:
https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/wiki/Successfully-requesting-and-integrating-new-features-and-improvements-in-GeoServer